# Configure AutoMapper to only get the property if it is available

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-5, automapper

We have the following mapping:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<MyObj, MyObjModel>()
                .ForSourceMember(x => x.MyObjDetails, y => y.Ignore())
                .ForMember(x => x.MyObjDetails, opts =>
                {
                    opts.MapFrom(x => x.MyObjDetails);
                });
```

Then I have the following function to retrieve MyObj:

```
public MyObj Get(Expression<Func<MyObj, bool>> predicate, bool? includeDetails = false)
        {
            MyObj result = null;

            try
            {
                using (var _context = new MyEntities())
                {
                    result = includeDetails.Value
                        ? _context.MyObjs.Where(predicate).Include(x => x.MyObjDetails).SingleOrDefault()
                        : _context.MyObjs.Where(predicate).SingleOrDefault();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) { throw e; }

            return result;
        }
```

So the mapping works great if includeDetails is true and we add "Include" in the query. It fails when we don't add "include" with the "Object is disposed..." exception. I understand that it fails because it tries to retrieve the property when the connection is closed. And that's fine.

Is there a way to tell AutoMapper to only get the property if it is available? EF6 does not set it to null after the context is disposed. So can we handle this?

We don't want to turn off Lazy Loading. We also want to be able to achieve the same result when we map this object as a list.

Thanks!